# log4j kafka appender doesn't use defined ConversionPattern

Tags: log4j, apache-kafka, apache-storm

I am running a Storm cluster which uses log4j for logging. I want to add a kafka appender in addition to the standard file-based logging.

My log4j config file looks like this:

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, A1

log4j.appender.A1 = org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.A1.File = /var/log/storm/logs/${logfile.name}
log4j.appender.A1.Append = true
log4j.appender.A1.DatePattern = '.'yyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.A1.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n

log4j.appender.KAFKA=kafka.producer.KafkaLog4jAppender
log4j.appender.KAFKA.Host=<kafka.ip>
log4j.appender.KAFKA.Port=9092
log4j.appender.KAFKA.Topic=storm_log
log4j.appender.KAFKA.SerializerClass=kafka.producer.DefaultStringEncoder
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.KAFKA.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %c{1} [%p] %m%n

log4j.logger.my.package.name=INFO, KAFKA
```

Everything works fine, except that the kafka appender doesn't use the defined ConversionPattern, even though the definition is exactly the same as in the file appender, which works as intended. How do I have to change the configuration to make the kafka appender work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issues with Kafka version 0.7.

There were some changes done to KafkaLog4jAppender in version 0.7.1 and after upgrading, the ConversionPattern works fine for me with a config similar to the one above.